# Closest number to a given one, but the number must be within selected variable increments as second argument

Tags: excel, vba

I am coding some functions with two arguments:

- First argument is a fixed given number
- Second argument is an increment value

The return value is a the number closed to the given first, but with the second argument increment.

The second argument will be ever from 0 to an integer.
For example:

- so 0.20 mean closet number endind must be 0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1 and so on
- or 5 mean closet number endind must be 0,5,10,15 and so on

For second example:

```
Number= RealStrike 270.12,0.5
Number must be 270

Number= RealStrike 270.12,0.2
Number must be 270.20

Number= RealStrike 2754.23,5
Number must be 2755
```

The function I tried is:

```
Function RealStrike(ByVal PrecioStrike As Double, ByVal FactorAjuste As Variant) As Double

    Dim PrecioStrikeInteger As Integer
    Dim IntMasCercano As Integer
    Dim Dif1 As Double
    Dim Dif2 As Double


    If IsNumeric(FactorAjuste) Then

        FactorAjuste = CDbl(Replace(CStr(FactorAjuste), ".", ","))

        PrecioStrikeInteger = Int(PrecioStrike)
        If PrecioStrikeInteger > PrecioStrike Then 
            FactorAjuste = -FactorAjuste
        ElseIf PrecioStrikeInteger < PrecioStrike Then abajo

        ElseIf PrecioStrikeInteger = PrecioStrike Then
            RealStrike = PrecioStrike
            Exit Function
        End If

        Dif1 = 1
        Dif2 = Dif1
    End If
        For i = 1 To 1 / Abs(FactorAjuste)
            Dif2 = Abs(PrecioStrike - (PrecioStrikeInteger + i * FactorAjuste))
            If Dif2 > Dif1 Then
                RealStrike = PrecioStrikeInteger + ((i - 1) * FactorAjuste)
                Exit Function
            ElseIf Dif2 < Dif1 Then
                Dif1 = Dif2
            End If
        Next i     
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Just woooo to the first answer, i did not know the MRound function. You save my day. It works like charm, also i love to use inbluid function as time procesing is the faster

Answer (score 1):

No need to reinvent the wheel, there is already a worksheet function that does exactly what you want.

```
Function RealStrike(ByVal PrecioStrike As Double, ByVal FactorAjuste As Variant) As Double

    RealStrike = Application.WorksheetFunction.MRound(PrecioStrike, FactorAjuste)

End Function
```

---

From [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.mround):

> ## WorksheetFunction.MRound method (Excel)
>
> Returns a number rounded to the desired multiple.
>
> ### Syntax
>
> *expression*.**MRound** *(Arg1, Arg2)*
>
> *expression* A variable that represents a WorksheetFunction object.
>
> ### Parameters
>
> - Arg1 | Required | Variant | Number - the value to round.
> - Arg2 | Required | Variant | Multiple - the multiple to which you want to round number.

Of course - you don't really need to wrap this into a function unless you absolutely wanted to. It's already a function in itself.